# Meld on OSX 10.10 - half screen

Tags: homebrew, window-manager

I installed [Meld](https://github.com/GNOME/meld) using homebrew on a stock OSX 10.10. It works, but it doesn't seem to understand the size of my screen (actually two screens, same behavior on both built in and secondary display). Meld window only occupies lower 2/3 of the screen and can't be moved above the invisible line. When I maximize it - it takes full lower 2/3 of the screen, upper 1/3 is available and I can drag other apps there.

This must be some known issue, sorry if my description is too vague.

Comment: seems like an X11 issue

Comment: I get the same thing with latest XQuarts =(